# How to load .dll file which returns assembly in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Is it possible to load .dll or static library(.a) file programmatially which returns assembly in objective-c for mac os x?

How assembly loading & unloading done in objective-c for mac osx?

Comment: What do you mean by assembly? Do you mean code written in assembly language? If so, what do you mean by loading a library which "returns assembly"? Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: .dlls are usually in windoze, .dylibs in os x. your question is too vague, please revise :)

Comment: Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath);  // For windows I want to achieve same for Mac where AssemblyPath is path of static library (libTEST.a) and i want to create instance of this library. Is it possible in Mac?

Comment: You can't DLLs in OS X. You can, however, load .dylibs, which are similar. Is that what you want?

Comment: DLLs are just another name for dylibs. "DLL" [stands for "Dynamically Loaded Library,"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) and "dylib" stands for ["Dynamically Loaded Library."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that even after reading Microsoft's documentation on the [`Assembly Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it's still not clear to me what an Assembly is. They say:

> Represents an assembly, which is a reusable, versionable, and self-describing building block of a common language runtime application.

The "reusable, versionable and self-describing" part sounds like a framework.

If indeed that's what you want to load, then you have a number of options. Your best best is to just link against the framework. The OS will automatically load it for you when your app starts up.

If you want to load it manually, there are a number of ways to do that. If it's a framework you're going to ship with your application, then you can simply put it into your app bundle's Frameworks folder, and then use:

```
NSBundle* frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"<your bundle's identifier>"];
if (frameworkBundle != NULL)
{
    [frameworkBundle load];
}
```

You can also use `dlopen()` (see `man dlopen(3)` for details). This will load a dynamic library into your process space.

I have never had a reason to use `dlopen()` directly. I usually just link against the framework. On those rare occasions where my app may need to run on an older OS that doesn't support the framework, I have used the manual loading described above via `NSBundle`.